# Where can I get individual files for my Laravel Framework?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am working with an inherited site based on the Laravel Framework which I upgraded from 5.6 to 8.0. I most aspects the site works great, but I occasionally sumble upon missing pieces. For example, I just discovered that the Reset Password feature does not work. Looking into it I find that there is a route for this:

```
Route::post('password/reset/{token}', ['as' => 'app.password.reset.post', 'uses' => 'App\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset']);
```

Yet there is no 'reset()' method in the ResetPasswordController. Additionally, the ResetPasswordController uses the trait 'ResetsPassword', yet there is no such trait located under

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
```

I tried checking the github repo for the Laravel framework, but these pieces were not there. I also looked under laravel-ui and didn't see them. According to the documentation,

"Laravel includes Auth\ForgotPasswordController and Auth\ResetPasswordController classes that contains the logic necessary to e-mail password reset links and reset user passwords. All of the routes needed to perform password resets may be generated using the laravel/ui Composer package"

I'm a little nervous about doing a general update as all other pieces are in place and working so I was looking for a way to obtain the individual pieces and have not found anything.

Here are my login routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'app'], function () {
    //Auth::routes();
    Route::get('login', ['as' => 'app.login', 'uses' => 'App\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);
    Route::post('login', ['as' => 'app.login.post', 'uses' => 'App\Auth\LoginController@login']);
    Route::post('logout', ['as' => 'app.logout.post', 'uses' => 'App\Auth\LoginController@logout']);
    Route::post('password/email', ['as' => 'app.password.email.post', 'uses' => 'App\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail']);
    Route::get('password/reset', ['as' => 'app.password', 'uses' => 'App\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm']);
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', ['as' => 'app.password.reset', 'uses' => 'App\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm']);
    Route::post('password/reset/{token}', ['as' => 'app.password.reset.post', 'uses' => 'App\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset']);
```

And this is what my ResetPasswordController looks like:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\App\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after password reset.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->redirectTo = route('app.dashboard');
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string|null  $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {
        return view('app.auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }
}
```

Also, from what I've read there is possibly an updated reset.blade.php. My question is what is my best approach to fix the reset password bug?

Comment: Is there any **running** version of your application? That could be checked for the missing files

Answer (score 0):

This is the trait for reseting passwords, that I found in my project, I hope it can help you somehow.

```php
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

trait ResetsPasswords
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showResetForm(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->route()->parameter('token');

        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
        // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
        // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation error messages.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function validationErrorMessages()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only(
            'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $password
     * @return void
     */
    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $this->setUserPassword($user, $password);

        $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

        $user->save();

        event(new PasswordReset($user));

        $this->guard()->login($user);
    }

    /**
     * Set the user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $password
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setUserPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            return new JsonResponse(['message' => trans($response)], 200);
        }

        return redirect($this->redirectPath())
                            ->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => [trans($response)],
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                    ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker();
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dusto - thank you. I placed it in the right place. HOwever it did not fix the error I've been getting - "Missing required parameter for [Route: app.password.reset.post] [URI: en-us/app/password/reset/{token}] [Missing parameter: token]. (View: /var/www/connectlytix-mar.14.22/resources/views/app/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php)" I also need to check my ResetPasswordController against the most recent one and the reset.blade.php.

Comment: Yes certainly, because there are 2 ways of reseting a password. 
1. is requesting a link after forgetting a password and then creating a new password when receiving that link
or 2. is when just changing the password, where the current password is known at that time.

The default variant of Laravel is sending a reset link. When you open the link, the token needed for verification is being passed to the view and later to the 'reset()' method. You either have to include that token and use reset link or have your own implementation of reseting a password